# Hibernate Error SQLGrammarException (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I try to get back a list of elements in an instance Criteria. In the execution I obtain this exception. What is the problem ?

The name of my database is "TransPlusBD".
The name of my table is a "gerant".
But the error indicates me that he(it) does not find the table "TransPlusDB.gerant_gerant", yet this table does not exist.
Normally we have to have his "TransPlusDB.gerant".

Code of the configuration

```
    properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:mysql://(cloud amazone aws).amazonaws.com:3306/TransPlusDB");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.username","xxx");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.password","xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.pool_size","4");
    configuration =  new Configuration();
    configuration.setProperties(properties);

    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Administrator.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(AutoGare.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Car.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(City.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Company.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(transplus.models.Configuration.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(DateDeparture.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Departure.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(HoursDeparture.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Luggage.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Manager.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Passenger.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(PlanningVoyage.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Route.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Stopover.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(SysAdmin.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ticket.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(TypeCar.class);

    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(ModificationLuggage.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(ModificationTicket.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(PassageRoute.class);

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
```

Code of my class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gerant")
public class Manager implements Serializable // Table Gerant
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "code_gerant")
   private long code_manager;

  @Column(name = "matricule_gérant",unique = true)
  private String matricule_manager;
  @Column(name = "nom_gerant")
  private String lastName_manager;
  @Column(name = "prenom_gerant")
  private String firstName_manager;
  @Column(name = "password_gerant",nullable = false)
  private String password_manager;
  @Column(name = "login_gerant",unique = true,nullable = false)
  private String login_manager;
  @Column(name = "poste_gerant")
  private String function_manager;
  @Column(name = "actif_gerant")
  private boolean enabled_manager;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
  @Column(name = "privilege_gerant")
  private Privilege privilege;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "code_manager", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_gerant_manager"))
private Administrator administrator;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "over_gerant", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_over_gerant"))
private Manager overManager;

@Expose   // Annotation for Gson
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = false)
private List<Manager> underManagers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Code for the recovery of the list.

```
public String getAllManager()
{

    if(session.isOpen())
    {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try
        {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Manager.class);
            List list = criteria.list();
            transaction.commit();
            if(list != null)
            {
                if(!list.isEmpty())
                    return serializeTab(list);
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if(transaction != null)
                transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is the raised exception

```
    this = {ServiceManager@3681} 
transaction = {TransactionImpl@3683} 
transactionCoordinator = {JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl@3979} 
transactionDriverControl = {JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl@3980} 
valid = false
e = {SQLGrammarException@3954} "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"
    sqlException = {MySQLSyntaxErrorException@3958} "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'TransPlusDB.gerant_gerant' doesn't exist"
    SQLState = "42S02"
    vendorCode = 1146
    next = null
    detailMessage = "Table 'TransPlusDB.gerant_gerant' doesn't exist"
    cause = {MySQLSyntaxErrorException@3958} "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'TransPlusDB.gerant_gerant' doesn't exist"
    stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[0]@3961} 
    suppressedExceptions = {Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList@3962}  size = 0
    sql = "n/a"
```

Help I PLEASE

Comment: Could you please specify your software versions, especially the Hibernate version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table `gerant_gerant` is a join table for a self association for this

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = false)
private List<Manager> underManagers = new ArrayList<>();
```

You need to let Hibernate to create this table using the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property or you can create it manually with constraints ( a foreign key, a unique key).

You can specify a join table name with the `@JoinTable` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I added this line of code at the level of the configuration

```
        properties.put("hbm2ddl.auto","validate");
```

Then this code at the level of my class

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = false,mappedBy = "overManager")
private List<Manager> underManager;
```

Thank